# check if the data already exists in table get the id of the row laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to add a condition while storing data in database that if the phone number is already exist in table then get the user id! otherwise add a new user how can a do this?

```
 function store(Request $request){

    if (Client::where('phone_number', '=', Input::get('phone_number'))->exists()) {
        // user found 
     }

   $client = new client();
   $client->name = $request->get('name');
   $client->phone_number = $request->get('phone_number');
   $client->email = $request->get('email');
   $client->save();


   return redirect('faq')->with('success', 'Task Created Successfully!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`updateOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)?

```php
Client::updateOrCreate(
    ['phone_number' => $request->get('phone_number')],
    ['name' => $request->get('name'), 'email' => $request->get'email')],
);
```

If you only need to fetch or create a `Client` without updating them, use [`firstOrCreate`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models) instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use your logic like this.

```
    function store(Request $request){
    $client =  Client::where('phone_number', '=', Input::get('phone_number'))- 
    >first();

    if (empty($client)) {
        $client = new client();
     }
   
   $client->name = $request->get('name');
   $client->phone_number = $request->get('phone_number');
   $client->email = $request->get('email');
   $client->save();


   return redirect('faq')->with('success', 'Task Created Successfully!');
}
```